# Group by and provide groups only if unique in group

Tags: sql, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

i have the Following dataset :

```
     Amount     Document Number
0     200           12345
1      90            2222
2     200          456789
3      90            4444
4     300            4789
5     300            4789
```

So basically i want to get group numbers for the above data (using ngroup maybe)

Grouping the data on the basis of amount. assign a group number to one group only if the Document numbers in that group has unique numbers. 
This is what i would like the outcome to be.

```
     Amount    Document Number  Group
0     200           12345          1
1      90            2222          2
2     200          456789          1
3      90            4444          2
4     300            4789            
5     300            4789
```

Comment: `df['Group'] = df.groupby('Amount').cumcount().add(1)`?

Comment: I don't understand why 2 and 3 have different groups.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand a requirement incorrectly within my problem. i have edited the original question.. Hopefully the question is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

> Grouping the data on the basis of amount. assign the rows to one group only if the Document number is a unique number.

I *think* you want `rank()`:

```
select t.*, rank() over (order by amount, document_number) as grouping
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, you could first create a mask where any group by amount has a dup is flagged as `False` with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) and [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), then use this mask and [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) like:

```
mask_dup = ~(df.duplicated().groupby(df['Amount']).transform(any))
df.loc[mask_dup, 'Group'] = df[mask_dup].groupby('Amount').ngroup()+1
print (df)
   Amount  Document Number  Group
0     200            12345    2.0
1      90             2222    1.0
2     200           456789    2.0
3      90             4444    1.0
4     300             4789    NaN
5     300             4789    NaN
```

if you have more than the two columns at first you need to specify the subset in `duplicated`